# Why do I take java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, bytebuffer, bufferunderflowexception

I take BufferUnderflowException from following code.

```
int length = mBuf.remaining();
char[] charBuff = new char[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
   char[i] = mBuf.getChar();
}
```

mBuf is a ByteBuffer. Line "char[i] =mBuf.getChar();" is crashed.

What do you think about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly assumed that a char is one byte in size.  In Java, a char is two bytes, so `mBuf.getChar()` consumes two bytes.  The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getChar--) even states that the method reads the next two bytes.

If you use the CharBuffer returned by [mBuf.asCharBuffer()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asCharBuffer--), that buffer's remaining() method will give you the number you expect.

**Update:** Based on your comment, I understand now that your buffer does in fact contain one-byte characters.  Since Java deals with the entire Unicode repertoire (which contains hundreds of thousands of characters), you must tell it which Charset (character-to-byte encoding) you are using:

```
// This is a pretty common one-byte charset.
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;

// This is another common one-byte charset.  You must use the same charset
// that was used to write the bytes in your ObjectiveC program.
//Charset charset = Charset.forName("windows-1252");

CharBuffer c = charset.newDecoder().decode(mBuf);
char[] charBuff = new char[c.remaining()];
c.get(charBuff);
```

Comment: actually, I write byte series in a file with objective c. then, I need to read these with java. in obj c, char type is one byte.